# ClassNotFoundException while readObject from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, objectinputstream

I have a problem with readObject() from ObjectOutputStream.

I'm trying to readObject on the server side. I have the same Message class in both Client and Server projects. I read that I need to have exactly the same Message class both in Client and Server (with the same package as well) but i don't know how to do this in NetBeans.

I tried to add Server Project to Libraries in Client by Libraries->Add Project->I chose the Server.jar but now I got the exception:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Piotr\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FXClient jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXClient\build\built-clean.properties
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXClient\build\built-clean.properties
Duplicated project name in import. Project jfx-impl defined first in C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXClient\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml and again in C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXServer2\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml
FXServer2.init:
FXServer2.deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXClient\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXServer2\build
C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXClient\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3767: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXClient\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1400: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXClient\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1430: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXServer2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1395: Unable to delete file C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXServer2\dist\run532287538\FXServer2.jar
```

Message class implements Serializable, I also added 
`protected static final long serialVersionUID = 111L;`
line to both Message classes before and this didn't change anything.

How should I import Message class to both Server and Client projects?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the common classes (Message class) to a separate project, and add it to both client and server projects as dependency...